# cant get the single selected item value of kendo multiselectbox using Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I want to get the selected value of my mutiselect box my component is :

```
<div class="example-config">
    Selected Values: {{selectedValues | json}}
</div>
<div class="example-wrapper">
  <p>T-shirt size:</p>
  <kendo-multiselect [data]="listItems" [(ngModel)]="selectedValues"  (select)="onSelect()"></kendo-multiselect>
</div>
```

`

this gives my the all selected items in array [item1,item,2,..]

i need to get only the selected one,in jquery it has a select event but in angular do we have as such?

Comment: Checking the docs it seems that it is not posible. In multiselect it will always return an array of all selected values. Why do you need just one selected in multiselect. Maybe there is an other way around.

Comment: @SehaxX i have a multiselect box binded with diffrent car brands power,by selecting any of them i want the chart plots the respective car power,now imagine if i select 10 cars,you should see 10 plots in single chart,the problem with this multiselect is everytime i pass to my database an array of carID not the selected one